# How to combine normal distributions to have a mixture with specified kurtosis

Tags: estimation, simulation, inference, kurtosis

I want to generate random samples from Normal Distributions $N(\mu_i,\sigma_i)$ by fixing kurtosis parameters ($\beta$s), as I need to simulate data by varying $\beta$ for my problem. I am trying to proceed as given in An and Ahmed (2008):
Consider a mixture of two normal distribution $p_1N(\mu_1,\sigma_1)+p_2N(\mu_2,\sigma_2)$. If $\mu_1=\mu_2$, then kurtosis parameter of this mixture distribution is $\beta^*=3\frac{(p_1\sigma_1^4+p_2\sigma_2^4)}{(p_1\sigma_1^2+p_2\sigma_2^2)^2}$. In this setting $\beta^*$ has minimum value of 3 when either $p_1$ is 0 or 1 and a maximum value of $\frac{3}{4}(\frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_2^2}+\frac{\sigma_2^2}{\sigma_1^2}+2)$ when  $p_1=\frac{\sigma_2^2}{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}$.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but normal distribution has a fixed kurtosis. The excess kurtosis is always equal to zero. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Kurtosis.html Do you want to combine several normal distributions so their combination has a specific kurtosis?

Comment: yes I want to combine several normal distributions

Comment: What is fixed and what can be changed? I suppose that the kurtosis of the mixture is given. Can I change $k$ or is it fixed? Can I change $\mu_i$ as well as $\sigma_i$?

Comment: in my study $k$ will vary from 4-10, $\mu_i$ and $\sigma_i$ can take any values.

Comment: This is strictly insoluble, I guess. A given kurtosis could arise from many quite different distributions if the means and SDs can both vary, even for a fixed $k$. What is more those mixtures can have varying skewness. I would back up one level and tell us why you think you must approach whatever problem you have in this way. What is the real problem, in short?  I suspect the advice will be to use something much simpler, say just $t$ distributions with differing degrees of freedom.

Comment: Note that kurtosis must be at least $1$ (at least $-2$ if you prefer to subtract $3$). So the notation implying that it could be any real value is inappropriate, although that is clearly an incidental detail.

Comment: I am trying to proceed as given in An and Ahmed (2008):

Consider a mixture of two normal distribution $p_1N(\mu_1,\sigma_1)+p_2N(\mu_2,\sigma_2)$. If $\mu_1=\mu_2$, then kurtosis parameter of this mixture distribution is $\beta^*=3\frac{(p_1\sigma_1^4+p_2\sigma_2^4)}{(p_1\sigma_1^2+p_2\sigma_2^2)^2}$. In this setting $\beta^*$ has minimum value of 3 when either $p_1$ is 0 or 1 and a maximum value of $\frac{3}{4}(\frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_2^2}+\frac{\sigma_2^2}{\sigma_1^2}+2)$ when $p_1=\frac{\sigma_2^2}{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}$.

Comment: For $p_1=0$ we generate from normal distribution with $\beta$=3, and for $p_1>0$, we generate from $\beta>3$. In both cases, our interest is to compare Unrestricted and Restricted (under equality of $\beta$s)Estimators through Simulated Relative Efficiency.

Comment: Theoretically Restricted estimator should perform poorer as we move away from the equality of $\beta$s, but in my case, it is reversed. I am not sure, what should I do to get the results in line with the theory.

Comment: Could you incorporate this additional information into the question, and also clarify what you mean by Unrestricted and Restricted here?

Comment: Also, if you are purely interested in kurtosis, can you make additional constraints, such as $\mu_1=\mu_2, \sigma_1=1$, etc.?  I'm assuming $\sum p_i=1$, correct?

Comment: unrestricted estimator is the usual estimator which doesn't incorporate uncertain prior information that all the kurtosis parameters are the same, while restricted estimator is the one which incorporates this uncertain prior information and pool all the unrestricted estimators into one estimator.

Comment: yes I can make additional constraints, and I am interested in kurtosis only.